# SQL Query for Tracking User Path Flow in Looker Studio using Sankey Chart

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I'm working on a SQL query to analyze user navigation paths in Google Analytics data, specifically for visualization in a Looker Studio Sankey chart. Looker Studio's Sankey chart requires the data to be structured with 'source' and 'destination' columns and you cant add more than 2 dimensions. I'm trying to track paths that start from a specific referrer and then follow the sequence of page locations that users navigate through.

Here's my base query:

```
WITH cleaned_data AS (
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_referrer') AS raw_page_referrer,
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS raw_page_location
  FROM
    `<table_id>`
  WHERE
    event_name = 'page_view' AND
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
    AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
),
referrer_and_location AS (
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    CASE
      WHEN raw_page_referrer LIKE '%mydomain.com%' THEN 'raw_page_referrer'
      ELSE 'entrance'
    END AS cleaned_referrer,
    raw_page_location AS cleaned_location
  FROM
    cleaned_data
)

SELECT
  cleaned_referrer AS page_referrer,
  cleaned_location AS page_location,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS values
FROM
  referrer_and_location
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING page_referrer = 'mydomain.com/homepage' AND values > 10
```

I want to modify this query to find paths that start with a specific page referrer. The goal is to track the sequence of page locations users go to after the referrer, then consider the current page locations as the new referrer, and so on. This would allow us to analyze user flow from the initial referring page.

The challenge is structuring this data to fit into the source/destination format required by Looker Studio's Sankey chart, and I'm struggling to adjust my query accordingly.

Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to modify this query to achieve the desired outcome?